# Arch Linux not recognizing Kobo e-reader

Tags: usb, arch-linux, macbook-pro-retina, ereader

I'm trying to get my Arch Linux installation to recognize a Kobo Aura H2O e-reader.

I've connected it via USB, which starts charging the reader. Usually within a second or two, the reader itself asks whether to connect to the computer, which I allow it to do.

After this, the reader doesn't show up as a mounted or unmounted drive, though.

I've tried to look at the output of `lsusb`, but it doesn't show up there, either.

Finally, I can't find it under `/dev/sd*`.

My OS is installed on a 2012 Retina MacBook Pro.

How can I get my computer to recognize this e-reader?